# How to fit fixed width elements in a fixed width container?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent element (div) with a fixed width of 1200px. There are no borders or padding on this element.

I have three inline child elements (divs) with fixed widths of 400px. Again, no borders, padding or margins.

I want my three child elements to sit on the same line but instead the third one gets pushed down. If I reduce their widths to 397px they all sit on the same line.

Why can't I divide the width of a parent container exactly by the number of children I want to sit abreast within that container? Much the same way that I can't define those child elements as percentage widths that add up to 100% (ie four children of all 25% width)?

Comment: Reset your CSS `* {margin:0;padding:0;border:0}` Or keep in mind browsers add `margins`, `padding`, and `borders`  where you might not be aware of or expect it.

Comment: `word-spacing` and the white space between the closing and opening of adjacent child elements can cause this. Do you have a code example?

Comment: Use box sizing `*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to the extra spacing cause by the white space in the code itself. You can fix it by either writing the markup in a way that makes sure there are no white space or you can set the parent `div`'s `font-size` to 0 so no white space is visible (make sure you then set the children `div` font's size back to normal)

In this example I've used the first method as it is cleaner

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

style

```
.parent {
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: #333;

  margin: 20px 0; /* outer margin doesn't matter */
}

.parent .child {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

The first box doesn't work, the second does as I've left no space between the closing and opening tags of the child elements

http://jsbin.com/cifedis/edit?output

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because someone closed my question (very rude). What I'm doing is setting `font-size: initial` on all elements (by using the `*` selector), and then I can set `font-size: 0` on the elements that have nested side-by-side elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add css like this=>

```
   .parent_container{
      width:1200px;
      float:left;
    }

   .child1,
   .child2,
   .child3{
      float:left;
      width:400px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `float:left` to your children in order to achieve this

```css
.parent {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child1</div>
  <div class="child">Child2</div>
  <div class="child">Child3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` elements (which I'm guessing you are using), by default, have a white space after them, which might cause the issue you are seeing.
There are a number of ways to remove this in the html itself, one of them being adding a comment between the two inline-block elements. I prefer this approach, as its more readable.

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div><!--
  --><div class="child">2</div><!--
  --><div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

You can also start the divs in the same line, like below, forgoing the comment 
`<div>content</div><div>
 content</div`

Answer (score 0):

Just Give Parent Div `Font Size 0px` Below is the Code,

You Can Also do the same by `float Left` But This is the Best Way :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Pratice</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<style>
    .contaniner {
        width:1200px; 
        font-size: 0px;
    }
    .threelock {
        background: #000;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .yllow {
        background: yellow;
    }
    .red {
        background: red;
    }
</style>

<body>

<div class="contaniner">
    <div class="threelock"></div>
    <div class="threelock red"></div>
    <div class="threelock yllow"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of solution I prefer `flexbox`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex:1 1 400px;
  background-color:red;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

If you really want to use with `inline-block` either make `font-size:0;` to the parent or do not change the line while creating children element

```css
.parent{
  width:1200px;
}
.child {
  background-color:red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <!-- Do Not change line of children-->
  <div class="child">1</div><div class="child">2</div><div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

please read details https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/